# Jenkins Shared library can access job parameters

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, environment

EDIT: I just had to ensure the pipeline plugins in Jenkins were as up-to-date as possible.

I created a Shared library on my local Jenkins instance. Single master node running on windows. It was an abstract pipeline that other pipelines could then leverage. Everything ran fine until I moved to a Jenkins instance on a linux box. The environment {} step in the pipeline doesn't appear to be being run so I had to put a script {} step in at the start of my stage to essentially setup the environment variables. Unfortunately these aren't propagating through the execution and it looks like I'll have to pass them down manually in a map? Could this be a shared library plugin issue I'm seeing or perhaps the version of Jenkins itself?

Thanks,
Mark.

I have a Jenkinsfile as follows

```
@Library("lifeSharedLibs") _
standardLifePipeline {
    projectName = "CheckmarxTestProj"
    recipientListDefault = "myemail@address.com"
    cxHost = 'https://checkmarxserver'
    cxDomain = 'domain'
    cxGroupId = 'groupId'
    cxHighThreshold = 1
    cxMediumThreshold = 5
    cxLowThreshold = 3
}
```

which references a sharedPipeline as below. You can see how I've replicated the environment slightly in the script inside the Checkmarx stage. Without this the variables weren't available to the calling checkmarxScan definition.

```
 def call(body) {

    def pipelineParams = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = pipelineParams
    body()

    pipeline {

        agent any

        tools {
            maven 'Maven_3.2.3'
            jdk 'java-8'
        }

        environment {
            cxProjectName = "${pipelineParams.projectName}"
            jobName = "${cxProjectName}" + ' CheckMarx Scan'
            gitHost = 'https://github.com'
            branchName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
        }


        stages {
            stage('Checkmarx Scan and New Issue check') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        // Duplicating the environment section above
                        cxProjectName = "${pipelineParams.projectName}"
                        jobName = "${cxProjectName}" + ' CheckMarx Scan'
                        gitHost = 'https://github.com'
                        branchName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"

                        // email parameters
                        recipientListDefault = """ ${pipelineParams.recipientListDefault}"""
                    }
                    checkMarxScan(cxProjectName: "${pipelineParams.projectName}"+ "_" + branchName,
                            cxHost: "${pipelineParams.cxHost}",
                            cxDomain: "${pipelineParams.cxDomain}",
                            cxGroupId: "${pipelineParams.cxGroupId}",
                            cxHighThreshold: "${pipelineParams.cxHighThreshold}",
                            cxMediumThreshold: "${pipelineParams.cxMediumThreshold}",
                            cxLowThreshold: "${pipelineParams.cxLowThreshold}",
                            cxIncremental: params.CHECKMARX_INCREMENTAL_SCAN,
                            cxExcludeFolders : "${pipelineParams.cxExcludeFolders}",
                            cxRecipientListDefault : "${pipelineParams.recipientListDefault}"
                    )
                }
                post {
                    always {
                        echo "Post scan"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                echo "Build completed. currentBuild.result = ${currentBuild.result}"
            }

            changed {
                echo 'Build result changed'
                script {
                    if (currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
                        echo 'Build has changed to SUCCESS status'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the start of checkmarxScan groovy method that was previously able to reference the environment variables looks like

```
def call(Map scanParams) {

    echo "The scanParams are " + scanParams
    echo "The cxProjectName variable set in the environment{} is " + cxProjectName
```

Comment: can you share example for your case. From the explanation it seems the issue should not be present. Cause i have similar implementation and works fine

Comment: Thanks Prasad, I've updated in the original question.

Comment: Now it appears when statements aren't being parsed correctly

    when { expression { return params.INCLUDE_CHECKMARX } }
                steps {
                    echo "Checkmarx scan is included " + params.INCLUDE_CHECKMARX

the echo outputs the params.INCLUDE_CHECKMARX to false yet it shouldn't have gotten to the echo if that was the case?

Comment: you can access env variables in pipeline with env.cxProjectName. So you don't need to duplicate the environment variable section. Also about above issue I would like to see the code.

Comment: Also environments are not mutable, so if you want to modify value of some environment variable inside some stage then you should use global variables. you can use them by declaring in any script section script  { env.variableName = ''value '}. These are accessible to all stages using env.variableName and you can also modify the value.

Comment: Hi Prasad, it turns out that the version of the various pipeline plugins I had was much older than the version of Jenkins I developed the sharedPipeline on. Thanks very much for your help!